# Can't texture model properly

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl, blender

My Blender 3D object that was exported with triangulated faces and UV's written doesn't apply the texture properly.

It looks like this:
[image: Screencap of the render of a cup. It looks alright I guess...]

My render code:

```
    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(ObjFace face : model.faces){
        float[] vertex1 = model.vertices[face.indices[0]-1];
        float[] vertex2 = model.vertices[face.indices[1]-1];
        float[] vertex3 = model.vertices[face.indices[2]-1];
        float[] normal1 = model.normals[face.normals[0]-1];
        float[] normal2 = model.normals[face.normals[1]-1];
        float[] normal3 = model.normals[face.normals[2]-1];
        float[] tex1 = model.texCoords[face.texCoords[0]-1];
        float[] tex2 = model.texCoords[face.texCoords[1]-1];
        float[] tex3 = model.texCoords[face.texCoords[2]-1];
        glNormal3f(normal1[0], normal1[1], normal1[2]);
        glTexCoord2f(tex1[0], tex1[1]);
        glVertex3f(vertex1[0], vertex1[1], vertex1[2]);
        glNormal3f(normal2[0], normal2[1], normal2[2]);
        glTexCoord2f(tex2[0], tex2[1]);
        glVertex3f(vertex2[0], vertex2[1], vertex2[2]);
        glNormal3f(normal3[0], normal3[1], normal3[2]);
        glTexCoord2f(tex3[0], tex3[1]);
        glVertex3f(vertex3[0], vertex3[1], vertex3[2]);
    }
    glEnd();
```

The parsing code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        String[] spaced = lines[i].split(" ");
        if (lines[i].startsWith("v ")) {
            float[] vertices = new float[3];
            vertices[0] = parseFloat(spaced[1]);
            vertices[1] = parseFloat(spaced[2]);
            vertices[2] = parseFloat(spaced[3]);
            verticesArray.add(vertices);
        } else if (lines[i].startsWith("vn ")) {
            float[] normals = new float[3];
            normals[0] = parseFloat(spaced[1]);
            normals[1] = parseFloat(spaced[2]);
            normals[2] = parseFloat(spaced[3]);
            normalsArray.add(normals);
        } else if (lines[i].startsWith("vt ")) {
            float[] texCoords = new float[2];
            texCoords[0] = parseFloat(spaced[1]);
            texCoords[1] = parseFloat(spaced[2]);
            texCoordsArray.add(texCoords);
        } else if (lines[i].startsWith("f ")) {
            int[] faceIndices = new int[3];
            int[] faceNormals = new int[3];
            int[] faceTextureCoords = new int[3];
            faceIndices[0] = parseInt(spaced[1].split("/")[0]);
            faceIndices[1] = parseInt(spaced[2].split("/")[0]);
            faceIndices[2] = parseInt(spaced[3].split("/")[0]);
            faceNormals[0] = parseInt(spaced[1].split("/")[2]);
            faceNormals[1] = parseInt(spaced[2].split("/")[2]);
            faceNormals[2] = parseInt(spaced[3].split("/")[2]);
            faceTextureCoords[0] = parseInt(spaced[1].split("/")[1]);
            faceTextureCoords[1] = parseInt(spaced[2].split("/")[1]);
            faceTextureCoords[2] = parseInt(spaced[3].split("/")[1]);
            faceArray.add(new ObjFace(faceIndices, faceNormals, faceTextureCoords));
        }
    }
```

Although I'm not sure if it could be a problem with my Blender export.

Thanks.

EDIT: Updated pic after I made the texture image's width and height powers of two.
[image: yeah]

Edit 2: I tried a simple box to make sure that it wasn't the model that was screwing up and tested the face culling. On the box, culling the back faces fixes the problem to some extent however, on the cup it makes little difference.
[image: boxculling]

Edit 3: I included a video to demonstrate what I think is the problem. I think that the triangular glitch is caused by overlapping triangles like with the handle is in front of the actual cup. [youtube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpt75ay0Oyc)

Comment: Can you show some examples of the face ("f") records in your OBJ file? Your parsing code assumes that each face has only 3 vertices, but they can have an arbitrary number of vertices in the OBJ format. If the exporting app only generates faces with 3 vertices, you're fine. Otherwise, you have a problem.

Comment: Yeah I used Blender to export the OBJ and checked the triangulate faces option. Here's the OBJ contents anyway (cup): [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1euoal7ndk2ydef/cup.obj?dl=0)

Comment: I tried that cup.obj model with a loader I wrote recently. It mostly looks fine. There's a small hole at the bottom of the handle, and some artifacts on the inside of the bottom part. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you posted. Can you show the `ObjFace` class, particularly the constructor?

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.com/UELC31D4
Although it is pretty much just assigning the arrays to the ones inside the object.

Answer (score 1):

Is that another instance of the 'textures that have sizes not power of 2' problem ? lwjgl will extend your texture to a power of 2 size, meaning your UV coordinates that are [0...1] will be wrong, they should be [0 ... 0.5783] because the rest is lwjgl padding to reach power of 2. Can't find a reference...

Comment: I guess that was part of the problem as there are no longer any black bits showing. So thanks for that! But there is still the problem where some parts are transparent. I updated my post to include a new pic of what it looks like after.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, in GLES20, the normals for a triangle are indicated by the winding (clock wise or counter clock wise). I'm not sure exactly what GL will understand if you set a normal per vertex (that's for lighting) and none for the triangle. I'm not sure you can set one for a triangle, meaning it will be computed from vertex position+winding. What makes me think it's a problem is the fact that all your quads are half rendered (one triangle in two).

Comment: I think you're right about the quads being half rendered. The model is exported from Blender with triangulated faces and UV's written. Also I haven't done any lighting in this so even if I don't include normals at all, this problem still occurs. I think Blender sets the order/direction of the vertices, normals and texture coords correctly.

Comment: Normals and winding order are separate things. Normals are used for lighting, the winding order is used for backface culling (if enabled).

Comment: Maybe it's ordering the vertices for a TRIANGLE_STRIP call. Anyways, from the second teapot and box, it seems you have a problem with normals. You could compute the triangle normal and make sure it kind of points in the direction of its vertices, or somehow ask Blender for a face normal and make sure your order reflects it.

Comment: But I'm not using any lighting... I could not include normals at all and this effect will still be there.

Comment: I mean, for one triangle, you have normals for the vertices (how the corner catches light) and normals for the triangle (where is inside and outside, for visibility culling). You can easily find the direction of the triangle normal (with a cross product), but depending on the order in which you take the cross product, it will point in a direction or its exact opposite, which makes sense since a triangle in 3d space has 2 faces, it's up to you which is the front one and which one is the back.

Comment: So GL will always consider that the side which is front is the one where you see the vertices in the order you input clockwise. Or counterclockwise (controlled by glFrontFace). But this has to be done in the same direction (cw or ccw) for all triangles. Did you try rendering the mug without backface culling ? If it's a problem with normals, all triangles will show.